# Rank of matrices with just a different column

Tags: algorithm, matlab, sparse-matrix, rank

I am currently writing a code in Matlab where I have to compute a ton of rank of matrices, a ton being from millions to billions or hopefully more. The most, the better.

These matrices usually differ, at each step, for just one column, of which I know the position. I was wondering if there was any "fast" algorithm, faster than Matlab one which uses svd, to compute the rank of such a family of matrices.

Additional info: Matrices are not very big, size being at most 100x100 and they are sparse.

Thanks in advance to anyone who could give some help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `rank(A)` ? Above is the MathWorks page of function `rank`:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rank.html

Comment: Yes, indeed the function rank uses the svd decomposition. I now modified the question